# Maven and a *VERY SLOW* internet connection: how to speed up download?

Tags: java, maven

My internet connection is VERY SLOW (< 50kbps, most of the time) and, because of that, I would like to know if there is a way to speed up the Maven download of the project's dependencies? I'm looking for a feature on Maven such as partitioned download, similar to Firefox's DownThemAll, Free Download Manager, Axel (linux) etc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xaade: If the answer lies in Maven configuration, wouldn't this be a relevant community to ask?  The product's use is pretty isolated to the programming community.  From the FAQ: *but if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*

Comment: But his *problem* has nothing to do with programmers, or the tool even, realistically.

Comment: yes, my question is about a tool (Maven) used by java programmers. Sorry, but I cannot find another place more suitable than here to place my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Configure yourself a local repository, which knows about the remote ones, and point your maven client to your local repo.

Your first download of each dependency will still be slow, as it still uses the slow internet connection, but subsequent ones will use the local cache.

Of course, if you depend mainly on SNAPSHOT versions, this won't give you much benefit, but for ones that don't change much, you'll win big time.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to set up a repository manager and configure it to pull things you like while you are sleeping, so that they will be there when you need them. There's nothing inside Maven for this.